# How do you attach the last executed PID to the primary prompt string?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I tried searching for an answer to this for a few hours now. I would like to attach the (base) designation to the (PS1?) variable and the current process ID being executed to the (PS2?) variable in .bashrc. I may be wording this incorrectly, but here is an image of what I would like to append to the prompt strings:[image]

Here is the C code used in the example above:
[image]

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. The image I am using omits the (base) and PIDs from the prompt strings.

I have tried appending $$ and $PPID to the variables.

Comment: Please paste text as text. Then show us what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried adding $$ and $PPID to both of the PS1 and PS2 variables. But this isn't grabbing the process I am looking for. I am  only in my second week of an operating systems class. The only reason I posted screenshots is because the ubuntu image seems to disable copying or pasting text from the VM to the host computer or vice versa. The screenshots are screenshots of screenshots from a PPT. I would have to manually type up everything in the images. This is not an assignment. Part of the issue is that I am not sure what documents to search through or search terms to use to help myself.

Comment: Please don't post images of text: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/70524 also, how did you add $$ to PS1?

Comment: I changed what was in .bashrc from PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ ' to PS1='$$ ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '. This displays the PID of the bash shell I think.

Comment: To use the clip board, you have to enable it in the settings of virtual box. You may have to enable it by installing the guest addons. For now I think it may be fair that you have images.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I actually did install guest add-ons, and enable those settings the other day. There was still an issue. That's another question for another day, but I ended up just giving up on that and installing xubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with either PS1 or PS2 or anything else relatd to your prompt or even your shell. You are running a C program and it is that program that is printing the PID. Just look at the code:

```
printf("(%d) addr pointed to by p: %p\n", (int) getpid(), p);
```

So, the number in the parentheses is PID of the process as returned by the `getpid()` call. That's why you're seeing it printed. If you change the line above to

```
printf("(foo:%d) addr pointed to by p: %p\n", (int) getpid(), p);
```

You will see it print `foo:` before the PID.

Comment: Oh jeez, alright, there's a valid explanation for this question. Here's what happened. He had other C programs that he gave us, which did not append the PID to the lines like this mem.c program does, there was another one with threads. But in class, he must have modified the code to include the PID on the threading program  so he could kill them easier but didn't give that code to us. I ran all of these a few days ago but overlooked this and went down a rabbit hole tonight. Do you perhaps know how he was able to append (base) to the prompt? Mine is listed without that.

Comment: @Zack that's simple, just `PS1="(base) $ "`.

Comment: I know I can do that, but I thought (base) was being assigned through some variable determining if the user is root or not. But thank you for all of your help.